# Insert background image as a d3js object

Tags: d3.js

I have a few charts made in d3js and I would like to add an image to some graph as a backround photo is there a specific function in d3js that can take an image an put it as a backgroud iamge for the svg. I dont want to declare the backroud image in the css.

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to declare the background image as such in CSS -- regardless of whether you're doing this statically or with D3. The only alternative would be to have a floating `<img>` element that you position appropriately, but that would be needlessly cumbersome.

Comment: yes I ve already did this but in this step my image is a dynamic input of the chart and it will be introduced with the data of the chart,this is why I dont want to use the css any more. and I cannot put my image in a div because the chart have to be ploted above the image so it like take the data: chart data+ backgroud image and plot chart above the bakgroud image(two layers graph)

Comment: @user1987 You can dynamically set `css` properties too.

Comment: for example I would like to plot some x and y positions of some objects placed in a specific area. So I can use in this case a scatter plot but it will be better to add the area layout(hause,street..) under the x and y axis and the data dots to add meaning to the obtained positions

Comment: Ok, so you could dynamically set [`background-image`](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_background-image.asp).

Comment: Thank you for the answer but I would like to change the style in the javascript so I added to my svg div an ID named 'svg' and then in the code I added this: document.getElementById('svg').style.backgroundImage='myurl'; but it didnt work.

Comment: Have you tried something like `d3.select("#svg").attr("background-image", "url(myurl)")`?